# Assign Clipboard data to a local variable with Firefox API

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How can I assign Clipboard text to a local variable using XPCOM. I need only to be worked in Firefox. Please suggest me any plugin or events to use. I have googled, but unable to find the article which matches my requirement. I heard something about

```
nsIClipboardCommands
```

but need assistance on how to use it.. And can I use this method in a web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) to achieve this.Or you can use these code:

```
function copyToClipboard(txt) {
    if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.clearData();
        window.clipboardData.setData("Text", txt);
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") != -1) {
        window.location = txt;
    } else if (window.netscape) {
        try {
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
        } catch (e) {
            alert("please goto ’about:config’\n and set ’signed.applets.codebase_principal_support’ to ’true’");
        }
        var clip = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);
        if (!clip)
            return;
        var trans = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);
        if (!trans)
            return;
        trans.addDataFlavor('text/unicode');
        var str = new Object();
        var len = new Object();
        var str = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);
        var copytext = txt;
        str.data = copytext;
        trans.setTransferData("text/unicode", str, copytext.length * 2);
        var clipid = Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard;
        if (!clip)
            return false;
        clip.setData(trans, null, clipid.kGlobalClipboard);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @user1008575: No, only in a Firefox extension. It might work on a webpage if the user changes his preferences - but that's temporarily, this functionality will be removed soon.

Answer (score 2):

See this : [Using the Clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Clipboard)